# How to create 'terms & conditions check box' in django?

Tags: django, django-models

[image]

I want to make a registration form like this, where user would type username,email,password,confirm password and check the terms and condition box to register his/herself. But i dont know how to create a model row for check box so that according to its input i would allow or disallow user to register.

models.py

```
class registeration(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    confirm_pasword = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: you don't need this field in your model.
if user don accept your term then cant register so why you want to save the information?
in your view check if user didn't accept you term then do nothing(sorry for bad English)

Comment: @S.MohammadMousavi but i in order to allow or reject i need to know weather user agrees with my terms or not! for that i need a field from where i can get data of acceptance or rejection so i can act accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) for this:

```
terms_confirmed = models.BooleanField()
```